# I deleted /etc/inputrc by mistake

Tags: 20.04

I look over internet for the file contents but I couldn't where can I find `/etc/inputrc` contents for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to copy the original file from your `/usr/share/readline` directory:

```
$ diff -s /usr/share/readline/inputrc /etc/inputrc
Files /usr/share/readline/inputrc and /etc/inputrc are identical
```